# How to get alert text message inside my notification center using titanium studio for android and ios

Tags: ios, titanium-alloy

I need to display alert message in notification center for both (iOS and Android) titanium App. I am using an enterprise apple account for my app.

I can play sound in the background service mode in titanium, but I also want to see alert message inside the notification center for my app.

Currently, I only see that inside `General -> profile -> my verified entriprise application`. How do I enable notification? I cant get alert text/badge in notification center and even there is no application settings inside settings in my iPad device.

This code is in place to register for push notifications:

```
Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
    types: [
        Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
        Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
        Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
    ],
    success:function(e)
    {
        var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
        label.text = "Device registered. Device token: \n\n"+deviceToken;
        Ti.API.info("Push notification device token is: "+deviceToken);
        Ti.API.info("Push notification types: "+Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationTypes);
        Ti.API.info("Push notification enabled: "+Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationsEnabled);
    },
    error:function(e)
    {
        label.text = "Error during registration: "+e.error;
    },
    callback:function(e)
    {
        // called when a push notification is received.
        alert("Received a push notification\n\nPayload:\n\n"+JSON.stringify(e.data));
    }
});
```

How do I get notification messages inside the application's notification center section?

Answer (score 0):

My assumptions from your questions:

- You want to use Appcelerator Arrow Push to send a push notification using https://platform.appcelerator.com
- You want the push notification to appear in the iOS Notification Centre

You code does not show that you actually send the deviceToken to Arrow or any other back-end where you'd send the push notification.

Please follow:
https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/latest/#!/guide/Subscribing_to_push_notifications-section-37551717_Subscribingtopushnotifications-SubscribingtoPushNotificationswithDeviceTokens

The app does not control where a push notification appears. This is controlled in iOS via Settings > Notifications per app.

Comment: Hi Fokke,

-> I read on your given article and for that i must require to include Ti.cloud manually. May be i can include it from my tiapp.xml by adding from module section but there is no ti.cloud module available to use. Please guide me to add ti.cloud module

Comment: -> Also please focus on my previously posted code as i need to register push notification service in my android and ios, For ios i also enabled push notification from my apple account and re-generated provisional profile for my App same as mentioned in this artical. But after deploy App, still my app setting in Ipad is not in settings section even anywhere. How to get message in notification center ?

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121904/registerforpushnotifications-doing-nothing

Comment: ti.cloud is included in the Titanium SDK, so just add require it via tiapp.xml as explained step by step in https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/latest/#!/guide/Subscribing_to_push_notifications. Here you'll also find how setting the notification types has changed in iOS 8. The code in the linked Q&A post and up here is for iOS <= 7.

Comment: Hi Fokke,
your given link shows 404 page not found error. Can we also use localnotification concept in titanium to get messages inside my notification center without enabling push notifications in my apple account,From Below page reference i seen about this and applied this in my code but notification did not appeared

Comment: http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/09/new-in-sdk-3-4-ios-8-interactive-notifications/

Comment: Yes, sorry we just changed the URLs of the nightly docs: https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/platform/latest/#!/guide/Subscribing_to_push_notifications

Comment: And yes, local notifications appear in the notification centre (unless the user has disabled that for the app) as well: https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Local_Notifications

Comment: hey Fokke, Finally we setup for local notification concept for our App and for that we read your provided doc as well : http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/09/new-in-sdk-3-4-ios-8-interactive-notifications/ , as provided in doc we changed sdk version to 3.4.0 to set local notification but after that it creates design issue. Ipad statusbar symbols (ipad wifi, ipad time, bettery) at top move to app background and app design crashes

Comment: You were using an SDK older then 3.4.0?

Comment: No, i was used it before but now i am using 3.4.1 sdk and with this also localnotification working fine but it creates design issues as i wrote in my previous comment

Comment: I fixed it, Actually instead of using CreateView, I used createlable to show thing black border, So now localnotification working properly in IOS. Thanks Fokke

Comment: Now, Set up for local notification in android titanium, i have seen link : http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Notification , But this link not opening. some errors there. If possible then send link to set localnotification for android as I did in IOS

Comment: Raj, that's the old docs, which should redirect you to http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Notification

Comment: Hello Fokke, FYI Your suggested link : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Notification   Not working. There is loader which just loading

Comment: Yes, we have docs problems :( Try https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/platform/latest/ for now